# Understanding style and layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-styles

I am very new to android.

This is my main activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);
        }
```

This is the main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="m.com.a0726.firstScreen">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally this is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppParent">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppParent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

While running in emulator, how does my layout pick up the style from `style.xml` even though it is not being mentioned anywhere? What if I want to refer to some other style from my layout?

Comment: Look at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The `android:theme` is specified in `application` and `activity` as attributes.

Comment: @Clive Seebregts: hah! perfect...Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base theme of your application is defined in your `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <!--This line-->
```

You can refer any style from your `styles.xml` in your layout XML files with the `style` attribute.

For example:

`styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <style name="ACustomStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Your layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        style="@style/ACustomStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Style is defined in the Android Manifest as an attribute of both application and activity nodes

Answer (score 0):

Check you AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

### android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

>

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: how your layout is picking up style.xml

Answer :-It is done by androidmanifest.xml file, i am showing you an example with my androidmanifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
```

Answer 2:- If you want to change style in any layout then you will define that style in your style.xml file . like these :-

```
 <style name="CustomFontStyle">
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
      <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>/> 
   </style>
```

To use these custom style in your layout file  , you can do these like :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_id"
      style="@style/CustomFontStyle"     ///these is that line for your ///custome style
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Style Inheritence :
Android supports style Inheritance in very much similar way as cascading style sheet in web design. you can do like these:-

```
<resources>
   ...
   <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff0000</item>
   </style>
   ...
</resources>
```

In your androidmanifest file you can use these MyCustomTheme like these :-

```
<activity
   android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
   ...
   android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
   />
```

Your new theme will be applied to your activity.For more details you can view these tutorial .http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/

Comment: @subham: great explanation.so if i want to add separate style to let's say 2nd activity then this is the way? but what i have in mainfest would be applied to all activities?

Comment: Ya i had actually indicated that thing that your default style of androidmanifest will be applied at every activity but If you want to apply separate style to 2nd(another) activity then i had shown a way there for a seperate activity by using these :-   <activity
   android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
   ...
   android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
   />